# SBT asks for credentials when creating a project

Tags: sbt

I am completely new to Scala and SBT. I have [downloaded](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) the `.tgz` archive for SBT 1.3.2, extracted it and added its `bin` directory to my `PATH` on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am following the [official Getting Started guide](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Hello.html), which gives a command to create a simple project. It is supposed to run like that:

```
$ sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
....
Minimum Scala build.

name [My Something Project]: hello

Template applied in ./hello
```

Instead, it asks me for credentials:

```
$ sbt new sbt/scala_seed.g8
[info] Set current project to code (in build file:/home/user/code/)
[info] Set current project to code (in build file:/home/user/code/)
Username:
```

I have no idea what to enter. I can't even try to guess, since I can only enter one character before it asks for a password. If I enter one character again, I get the username prompt again. This is the output after pressing two keys:

```
$ sbt new sbt/scala_seed.g8
[info] Set current project to code (in build file:/home/user/code/)
[info] Set current project to code (in build file:/home/user/code/)
Username: Password:
Username:
```

I just want to setup a basic project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe it is the underlying git checkout asking for credentials. Try a stand-alone git checkout/clone: `git clone git@github.com:scala/scala-seed.g8.git /tmp/scala-seed.g8` and see if this works.

Comment: Something seems to be trying to connect with a github account as I get this message when I move further forward: `https://github.com/scala/imba-hello.g8.git: not authorized` so in order to answer this question we need to know how to bypass the github login process and instead just download the project.

Comment: @mana 's answer does the trick however for someone new it's simply:  `git clone git@github.com:scala/scala-seed.g8.git scala-seed.g8` (or whatever you might like to call the project

Comment: The problem here is that template name is incorrect so I answered this clearly below.

Answer (score 6):

If you get `sbt new user/some.g8` asking for the `Username:` then you know that you have typed the template path e.g. `user/some.g8` incorrectly so it doesn't exist as a g8 template.

Please check that you have to correct template path and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Even I got the same error when I tried to create a new project following the instruction from https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html using sbt cli.
I ran the command as below,

```
sbt new hw/hello-world.g8
```

Following the above command I was prompted for suername and password. Then I ran it again as

```
sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

This time the project was successfully created.
Output:

```
hello-world.g8
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_261)
[info] set current project to scala (in build file:/C:/scala/)
[info] set current project to scala (in build file:/C:/scala/)

A template to demonstrate a minimal Scala application

name [Hello World template]: hello-world

Template applied in C:\scala\.\hello-world
```

So the **hw** in the command "sbt new **hw**/hello-world.g8" is not correct and it has to be only "sbt new **scala**/hello-world.g8".

Answer (score 0):

In the first, working example you have scala hyphen seed.

```
$ sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
....
```

In the second non-working example you have scala underscore seed.

```
$ sbt new sbt/scala_seed.g8
[info] Set current project to code (in build file:/home/user/code/)
[info] Set current project to code (in build file:/home/user/code/)
Username:
```